# Soap Request with XML Schema Parameter

Tags: xml, soap, request

can you help me out? I'm new to SOAP, and I don't know what to send as parameter here `<xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml`

```
<SendOrder xmlns="http://wMobSrv/wMobService">
      <dsOrder>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</dsOrder>
      <dsArticles>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</dsArticles>
      <dsResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</dsResult>
      <Database>string</Database>
</SendOrder>
```

Response:

```
["xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:soap": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"]

["xmlns": "http://wMobSrv/wMobService"]

["xmlns:msdata": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata", "id": "NewDataSet", "xmlns": "", "xmlns:xs": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]
["msdata:IsDataSet": "true", "name": "NewDataSet", "msdata:UseCurrentLocale": "true"]
[:]
["minOccurs": "0", "maxOccurs": "unbounded"]
["name": "Doc"]

["minOccurs": "0", "name": "Code_OE", "type": "xs:string"]
["minOccurs": "0", "name": "Code_Doc", "type": "xs:string"]
["minOccurs": "0", "name": "Num_Doc", "type": "xs:string"]
["minOccurs": "0", "name": "Status", "type": "xs:string"]
["minOccurs": "0", "name": "Description", "type": "xs:string"]
["xmlns:msdata": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata", "xmlns:diffgr": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"]
["xmlns": ""]
["msdata:rowOrder": "0", "diffgr:id": "Doc1", "diffgr:hasChanges": "inserted"]
```

Comment: could you please share the respose once you post this .... I hope you are using SoapUI to push it to server .... moreover if you can tell .... expected and actual output....?

Comment: I get SendOrderResult as false, Status N, and Description "No Connection"

Comment: could you please the the whole XML reponse?

Comment: I updated the question, the response was too long for here

Comment: Any idea, how to know what to send?

Comment: my friend i am still not sure ... what id main motive here .... please tell me what you are try to do .......... if you just want options for XSD then ..:XSD provides a set of 19 primitive data types (anyURI, base64Binary, boolean, date, dateTime, decimal, double, duration, float, hexBinary, gDay, gMonth, gMonthDay, gYear, gYearMonth, NOTATION, QName, string, ....... Let me know if it helps

Comment: could you please try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)   i hope you will get how to send it right way

Comment: I tried with different XSD and still I can't send an order. That's my question, what to send. What elements

Comment: can you show me one example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to look with Google to SOAP with Datasets. The schema is one part in the parameter and the actual data goes in a diffgram.